# Limit of a Sequence Involving Dirichlet Function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Here's my question:

> Let $a_n$ be a sequence and D(x) be the Dirichlet Function:
>    $$D(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &   x \in \Bbb Q   \\ 
> 0 & \mbox  x\notin \Bbb Q. \end{cases}    $$
>
> Is it true that If $a_n$ converges then $(a_n+D(a_n))$ converges.

Solution
I think that the statement is false. Take for instance the following sequence which converges to $0$.

$$a_n = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{n} &   n=2k     \\ 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}*n} & \mbox  n=2k-1 \end{cases}    $$

Therefore:
 $$(a_n+D(a_n)) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{n}+1 &   n=2k     \\ 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}*n} & \mbox  n=2k-1 \end{cases}    $$

The assumption here is that fact that $\sqrt{2}* n$ is always irrational.
The sequence $(a_n+D(a_n)) $ has two partial limits, first is $0$, if $n=2k-1$ and the second is 1 if n=2k.

Am I right here?

Thanks,

Alan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right. A simpler sequence (at least notation-wise) would be $a_n = 1/\sqrt{2^n}$, but your sequence works nicely as well.